# Как подставить значение из другой таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть две таблицы: "Сотрудники" и "Должности"
Нужно в итоге получить ответ (массив/объект php), совмещающий эти таблицы (пример для ИД=1), чтобы в ячейку "Должность" попало название должности, заменив цифру:

```
Array или Object ( [ИД] => 1 [Фамилия] => Мятлев [Имя] => Степан [Отчество] => Мечиславович [Должность] => Водитель )
```

Пробовал такой способ:

```
SELECT * FROM Сотрудники INNER JOIN Должности ON Сотрудники.Должность = Должности.ИД AND Сотрудники.ИД = '1'
```

Таким образом получается ответ:

```
Array или Object ( [ИД] => 1 [Фамилия] => Мятлев [Имя] => Степан [Отчество] => Мечиславович [Должность] => 3 [Значение] => Водитель )
```

Данный способ не подходит, т.к. в реальной задаче нужно получить данные из еще одной таблицы, в которой получаемое значение записано в столбец "Значение", и которое заменяет собой значение последней ячейки [Значение]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Данный способ не подходит, т.к. в реальной задаче нужно* Формулируйте сразу настоящую задачу. С формулированием адекватной модели у Вас не складывается. И таблицы следует давать не фотографиями, а скриптами CERATE TABLE и INSERT INTO, форматированным текстом. Не забудьте эталонный ответ для предоставленных данных и точную версию сервера.

Comment: @Akina, исправил, это случайно осталась часть из реального запроса

Comment: А для чего этот цирк с «нереальным запросом»?

Comment: *и которое заменяет собой значение последней ячейки [Значение]* Это неверно. В наборе присутствует два одноимённых поля. И если обращаться к сырому рекордсету позиционно, можно получить оба поля. А вот обращение по имени, в том числе и при формировании объекта, приводит к тому, что одно поле напрочь маскирует однофамильца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить алиас для нужного поля

```
SELECT Сотрудники.*, Должности.Значение Должность 
FROM Сотрудники 
INNER JOIN Должности ON Сотрудники.Должность = Должности.ИД 
WHERE Сотрудники.ИД = '1'
```

Comment: Я бы сказал не "можно", а "нужно".

Comment: Моё можно не в плане «для решения задачи можно..», а скорее «в СУБД есть такая возможность». К тому же можно получить всё, что есть в resultset по числовым индексам)